# I get an error **Error invoking Method 'addReview': Internal server error [500]

Tags: javascript, meteor

If I try to add reviews or like a recipe I get an error **Error invoking Method 'addReview': Internal server error [500] debug.js:41**,even though it adds reviews and likes into databases and works fine but still gives me above error.

Source code [Github](https://github.com/soni1/foody)

**add_review.js**

```
    Template.add_review.events({
        'submit .add-review':function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var rating = event.target.rating.value;
            var review = event.target.review.value;
            var recipeId = Router.current().data()._id;
            Meteor.call('addReview',rating,review,recipeId);
        }
    });
Template.recipes.events({
    "click [data-action='addLikes']": function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var recipe = Recipes.findOne({_id: this._id});
        Meteor.call('upvote',recipe)
    }
});
```

**client/methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    addReview:function(rating,review,recipeId){
        if(review!=""){
            Reviews.insert({
                rating:rating,
                review:review,
                recipeId:recipeId
            });
            Router.go('reviews',{_id:recipeId});

            FlashMessages.sendSuccess('Review Added',{ autoHide: true, hideDelay: 2000 });
        }
        else{
            FlashMessages.sendError('Review field is empty',{ autoHide: true, hideDelay: 3000 });
        }
        return false;
    },
    upvote:function(currentRecipe){


        var user = Meteor.user();
        if(!user){
            FlashMessages.sendError("You need to login to like this recipe", {hideDelay: 1000});

        }
        if (currentRecipe) {
            if (_.contains(currentRecipe.voters, Meteor.userId())) {
                FlashMessages.sendError("You already liked this recipe", {hideDelay: 1000});
                return false;
            }
            Recipes.update(currentRecipe._id, {$addToSet: {voters: Meteor.userId()}, $inc: {likes: 1}});
        }
    }
})
```

**server/permissions.js**

```
RecipesImages.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        return true;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function(userId, doc) {
        return false;
    },
    download: function(userId,doc) {
        return true;
    },
    fetch: null
});
Recipes.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        return true;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
    return true;
    }
});
Reviews.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        return true;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your methods are in /lib, not /client.  /lib gets executed both on the server and client, so I think your Router.go is messing things up...can you put that in a callback from the method?

Comment: @StephenWoods if i put my methods on server i get other error message Error invoking Method 'addReview': Method not found [404] .If i remove Router.go and methods are on server or lib it still gives me error.

Comment: your code is messed up: you can't use Router.go on the server, but you *must* define methods on the server. This doesn't make any sense. You'll need to try a completely different approach. It seems that you don't even need methods here. So why make life hard? Just use functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use methods where they are not needed and only make things harder. Isn't this all just client code? If so, you can just use functions:

**add_review.js**

```
Template.add_review.events({
    'submit .add-review':function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var rating = event.target.rating.value;
        var review = event.target.review.value;
        var recipeId = Router.current().data()._id;
        addReview(rating,review,recipeId);
    }
});
Template.recipes.events({
    "click [data-action='addLikes']": function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var recipe = Recipes.findOne({_id: this._id});
        upvote(recipe)
    }
});
```

**client/methods.js**

```
addReview = function(rating,review,recipeId){
        if(review!=""){
            Reviews.insert({
                rating:rating,
                review:review,
                recipeId:recipeId
            });
            Router.go('reviews',{_id:recipeId});

            FlashMessages.sendSuccess('Review Added',{ autoHide: true, hideDelay: 2000 });
        }
        else{
            FlashMessages.sendError('Review field is empty',{ autoHide: true, hideDelay: 3000 });
        }
        return false;
    };

 upvote = function(currentRecipe){

        var user = Meteor.user();
        if(!user){
            FlashMessages.sendError("You need to login to like this recipe", {hideDelay: 1000});

        }
        if (currentRecipe) {
            if (_.contains(currentRecipe.voters, Meteor.userId())) {
                FlashMessages.sendError("You already liked this recipe", {hideDelay: 1000});
                return false;
            }
            Recipes.update(currentRecipe._id, {$addToSet: {voters: Meteor.userId()}, $inc: {likes: 1}});
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

@Waqar First off, in your methods.js file, which as someone else has already told you should go in the /lib folder, you should have single quotes around your function name. I've re-written your code for Meteor.methods and for the Template.add-review.events below

client/templates/reviews/add_review.js (sorry, I put each template in a separate folder along with the js file for it)

```js
Template.add_review.events({
    'submit .add-review': function(event){
        var rating = event.target.rating.value;
        var review = event.target.review.value;
        var recipeId = this._id;
        
        var params = {
            rating: rating,
            review: review,
            _id: recipeId
        }
        
        Meteor.call('addReview', params);
        
        FlashMessages.sendSuccess('Review Added'); // and any other options you want to include 
        Router.go('reviews',{_id:recipeId});
        
        return false;
    }
});
```

/lib/methods.js

```js
Meteor.methods({
    'addReview': function(params){
        Reviews.insert(params);
    }
});
```

Give that a try and see if it works. Also, put your methods.js file in the /lib folder as Stephen suggested.

Comment: @waqar btw, I know that does not include your if statement, but I think you can handle that from here. :) and the code I shared is some code I've actually tested and run.